# Calcular el factorial de un número e imprimir el proceso

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código que calcula el factorial de un número en JavaScript, pero lo que quiero que muestre son los números justo como en la imagen.

```js
var n = 5,
  t = 1,
  q = document.querySelector('.n');


for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  t = t * (n - i);
}

q.innerHTML = (n + '! = ' + t);
```

```html
<span class="n"></span>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes concatenar el valor y luego usar el substring para eliminar el ultimo valor concatenado que en este caso seria la X

```js
var n = 5,
t = 1,
q = document.querySelector('.n');
var concat = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    t = t * (n - i);
    concat += n-i+' x ';
}

var factorial = concat.substring(0, concat.length - 3);

q.innerHTML = (n + '! = '+ factorial +' = ' + t);
```

```html
<span class="n"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un *buffer* que guarde los números mientras vas calculando el resultado:

```js
let n = 5,
  t = 1,
  q = document.querySelector('.n'),
  b = '';


for (let i = n; i > 0; i--) {
  if (i !== 1) {
    b += i + ' x ';
  } else {
    b += i;
  }
  t *= i;
}
q.innerHTML = (n + '! = ' + b + ' = ' + t);
```

```html
<span class="n"></span>
```

O puedes utilizar las funciones de ES6

```js
const n = 5;
const array = Array.from({length: n}, (x,i) => i+1);
const process = array.reverse().join(' x ');
const factorial = array.reduce((x, y) => x*y, 1)
const result = `${n}! = ${process} = ${factorial}`;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

Documentación:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) - Crea un arreglo a partir de ciertos parámetros
- [`Array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) - Da *vuelta* al arreglo
- [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) - Une al arreglo en un string
- [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - Ejecuta una función *reductora* en cada elemento del arreglo