# Factorial de los n primeros números en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer una función que dado un número n que se pide al usuario, calcular el factorial de los n números, es decir, si el número n=6, una función que devuelva el factorial de los 6 primeros números y lo devuelva por pantalla, es decir, que imprima, el factorial de 1, el de 2, el de 3, el de 4, el de 5 y el de 6.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Calcular el factorial de un número e imprimir el proceso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/236220/calcular-el-factorial-de-un-n%c3%bamero-e-imprimir-el-proceso);  [Factorial recursivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111638/factorial-recursivo)

Comment: No, no responde a mi pregunta

Comment: ¿Por qué no incluyes lo que has intentado?

Comment: ¿Porqué no responde a tu pregunta? Lo único "diferente" en las respuestas a esa pregunta es la obtención del valor "n" y la iteración desde 1 hasta "n". Tal parece que no se ajusta a lo que buscas sólo porque no aparece cómo pedir al usuario el valor "n" ni como iterar de 1 hasta "n". Te invito a repasar [ask]. Tienes suficiente reputación para saber como funciona el sitio. Las preguntas del tipo: *hazme la tarea* no son bien recibidas y por lo general terminan cerradas. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es una forma de hacerlo bastante sencilla, donde te muestra el número del cual se está haciendo el factorial, y posteriormente realiza el factorial de ese número a partir del cual el usuario introduce.

```js
var n = prompt("Introduzca el número del cual se quiere obtener el factorial:");

    do {
        var total = 1; 
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            total = total * i; 
        }
        console.log("Factorial de " + n + ": " + total);
      n--;
      } while (n > 0);
```

```html
<!doctype html>

    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
        <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <h1>Factorial</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda; cualquier duda no dudes en comentármela.

Comment: Es un problema clásico para resolver con una función recursiva.

Comment: Y así le has hecho los deberes al OP, básicamente la pregunta fue: *Necesito que alguien haga esta tarea por mi*, no muestra nada de lo que ha intentado y tampoco acepta una sugerencia de respuesta a un pregunta similar. No estoy valorando el contenido de tu respuesta, sólo valoro el si la misma cabe o no ante una pregunta tan pobremente formulada. Saludos

Comment: Aunque se agradece el aporte, evita responder a preguntas de baja calidad o en donde el OP no demuestre lo que ha intentado hasta el momento (es más, la pregunta era duplicada). Lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_.